# elasticsearch narrowing the search path

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a directory structure:

> w:\docs
>   w:\docs\set1
>   w:\docs\set2 etc.

In my config W:\docs is set as my root directory for elasticsearch. For most searches starting here is fine, but On some searches I know that the documents I’m looking for will be in set1 for instance. What do I need to set to tell Elasticsearch to limit the search to set1? I’m using Elasticsearch 5.5.1

I thought something like:

```
GET  myindex/_search?q=content:Dave AND (path.real=:w//Docs//set1//)
```

but if I have files with 'dave' in the root or set2 they still get returned

OR using the style :

```
GET myindex/_search
{
 "query": {
    "wildcard" : {
       "path.real" : "W:\\\\Docs\\\\set1\\\\*"
    }
}
```

will return only the documents in this directory, but I cant seem to combine it with content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
GET  myindex/_search?q=content:Dave AND (path.real=:"""w:\\Docs\\set1\\*""")
```